# How to write an If statement with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an assignment that I am working on for school and we had to create an ArrayList that takes in two parameters and stores them. Then I had to write an "if" statement and if there are no Movies then print a line but if there are movies then loop it and print every movies info. Well I'm having a hard time writing the if statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovieLibrary
{
private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
public String movieTitle;
public int movieRunLength;

public MovieLibrary()
{
    movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
}

public void addMovie(String title, int runLength)
{
    movies.add(new Movie(title, runLength));
}

public void printMovies()
{
    System.out.println("#################");
    if (movies == null){
         System.out.println("No movies in the library");
        }
    else{
        for (Movie movie : movies){
            movie.printMovieInfo();
        }
    }               
    System.out.println("#################");        
}
}
```

The code compiles and runs and the loop works (if there is information) but the message does not print if there isn't anything in the list.

Comment: if (movies == null || movies.isEmpty())

Comment: if(movies.isEmpty()) best choice

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (movies == null){
```

to

```
if (movies == null || movies.size() == 0){
```

If the list of movies is empty, that does not mean necessarily that it is `null`, you need to check its `size` too.

Comment: Perfect, it worked! For some reason I think I tried to put `movies.size() == 0` and it threw up on me but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these two options:

1. Write validation manually like

   if(null == movies || movies.size == 0)
2. Make use of Apache collection utils (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html)

   if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(movies))

I would suggest second option.

I hope, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(movies==null)
```

should be changed to

```
 if(movies.size()==0)
```